Median length in a random triangle
There are $3$ random points on the plane, whose coordinates are independent and have a standard normal distribution (univariate). Let's choose (with equal probability) one of the medians of the resulting triangle.
Find the length of this median.
There are $A_i(x_i, y_i)$.
$m_a = \frac{1}{2} (2c^2+2b^2 - a^2)^\frac{1}{2}, $
where $a = (x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2$ and so on. Next, I wanted to take the mathematical expectation from $m$.
This way looks cumbersome . Is there any other way to solve the problem?
P.S. Is it true that on average a given random triangle will be equilateral?

PS is not true, but if one draws a triangle on a blackboard it often comes out isosceles so your PS is a joke. Is the plane the full R^2

"Is it true that on average a given random triangle will be equilateral?" An average of what? By exchangeability, each angle has the same expectation, and each side has the same expectation, so you might say yes in that sense, but if you divide  the square of the perimeter by the area then the value of $\sqrt{27}$ for an equilateral triangle is the lowest possible and in no sense the expectation.

Empirically the mean value seems to be somewhere in $(1.53,1.54)$.

I believe the exact answer is for the expectation of the length of any of the triangle medians is $\frac{\sqrt{3 \pi }}{2}$ which is indeed what @Semiclassical states.

The length of one of the triangle medians can be written as $\sqrt{\left(\frac{\text{x1}+\text{x2}}{2}-\text{x3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\text{y1}+\text{y2}}{2}-\text{y3}\right)^2}$.  One sees the sum of the squares of two independent normal distributions with the same mean (0) and variance (3/2).
